# How can an elder address a teenager in a respectful way?

Tags: sanskrit

If in normal English, an elder wants to refer to a teenager in a respectful way, he can say something along the lines of "This young gentleman", what are the different ways the same can be done in Hindi and Sanskrit, as in what is considered a honorific title for the same ?

Comment: सभ्य नव युवक, सुशील नव युवक

Comment: Sorry... But...You are just translating to Hindi... I'm looking for some proper monikers...

Comment: http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=+gentleman&trans=Translate&direction=AU   is for gentleman  & this is for young in sanskrit  http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?page=1

Comment: सभ्य नव युवक, सुशील नव युवक  its a sanskrit also use in hindi and gujrati to address young gentleman

Comment: http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=young&direction=ES&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=   young man    कुमार kumAra m. young man http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?page=5

Comment: How is this question related to _Hinduism_? This is a grammar/language question. I posted this question as an example at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/91130/hindi-language